# Scrolling div stuck to bottom on content load

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple messaging app, but the messages have content that is sometimes very long. As such, I've implemented a "See more" and "See less" button that shows either the entire content, or a clipped version of the content, respectively. The chat view is inverted so that newer chats are closer to the bottom - if the scroll bar is all the way at the bottom of the scrollable div, clicking "See more" loads the content in, but the scroll stays stuck at the bottom (so a user would have to click "See more" and then scroll to the top of the long message to start reading). But if the user has scrolled even a tiny amount up, clicking "See more" behaves as expected, with the scroll staying fixed at the current location. How can I make it so that the scroll stays fixed at the current location, even if the user is scrolled all the way to the bottom of the div?

I've tried setting padding and margins to the bottom of the scrollable div, or automatically scrolling to the top of the message when it's clicked, but that didn't work and is even worse behavior (snapping back and forth).

Video attached for clarification on the behavior (first behavior is wrong, second is correct):
[link to video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/587N4.gif)

Simplified code below:

```
<JsxParser ... jsx={this.state.expanded ? wholeContent : clippedContent}/>
<div>
    <button className="link pt-2 p-1"
            onClick={() => this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})}>
        {this.state.expanded ? "See less" : "See more"}
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: It's *amazing* to me that SO has not fixed the onboarding process for new users.

Comment: Apologies, I have added in some simplified code. I didn't realize it was a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that these show more/less buttons work with onClick handlers. What you would want to do is to navigate the user to a place where the collapsed comment is on top of the screen. You could make the buttons into `<a></a>` tags, setting their `href` attributes to be equal to their corresponding message div's I'd preceded by a '#'.

Basically, a div element with `id="message1"` and the show more button to have `href="#message1"`.

Comment: That does work, but it snaps the `div` to the top of the scroll area, as expected. The ideal behavior is that the top of the content stays fixed in place, wherever it may already be located within the scroll area.